# Implementing Default on nested structures causes a stack overflow

Tags: rust, default

I found an unusual behavior of `std::default`. If you create a nested structure with default setters and try to create the highest level struct with default parameters, it causes a stack overflow.

This code compiles, but when you try to run it throws `thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack`:

```
use std::default;

pub struct A {
    x: i32
}

impl Default for A {
    fn default() -> A {
        A { ..Default::default() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test = A { ..Default::default() };
}
```

But if you set the defaults of inherited by props, it works:

```
use std::default;

pub struct A {
    x: i32
}

impl Default for A {
    fn default() -> A {
        A { x: 0 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test = A { ..Default::default() };
}
```

Is this a known issue and should I post it to the Rust issue tracker? My compiler version is `rustc 1.2.0-nightly (0250ff9a5 2015-06-17)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of *course* it causes a stack overflow.

To make this clearer, let's change the example a little:

```rust
pub struct A {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Default for A {
    fn default() -> A {
        A { x: 1, ..Default::default() }
    }
}
```

When you say `A { ..Default::default() }`, you *are not* saying "create me an `A` and execute `Default::default()` for each field".  This means that the implementation of `default` is **not** equivalent to:

```
A { x: 1, y: Default::default() }
```

It is, in fact, this:

```
let temp: A = Default::default();
temp.x = 1;
temp
```

So yes, it causes a stack overflow: you've defined the default value of `A` in terms of itself.

Comment: Hm. Interesting interaction. Thanks for clear explanation. But anyway, IMO, compiler shouldn't let me do this sort of stuff

Comment: @Cherrionella It's not the compiler's job to keep you from making logic errors or solve the halting problem. :)

Comment: @DK.: well, many forms of unbounded recursion which cannot possibly be what you wanted are trivial to detect, and one could easily form a case for the compiler complaining of such things.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: I didn't want to get bogged down in the comments section on the subject; I agree that detecting *almost certainly* incorrect behaviour in lints is a good thing, but I think expecting or relying on a language to detect all such mistakes is just *begging* for trouble.

Comment: @Cherrionella I've [submitted an issue](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/issues/103) to [rust-clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy), which I believe is more suited for this kind of thing than the rust compiler. If you are on nightly, consider yourself invited to try it.